# How do I get rid of a stuck train?

Tags: openttd

I have an old electric train that's been stuck for quite a while. During upgrading I upgraded the electric rail station to maglev while a train was in the depot. However, the train was never "stopped" in the depot. I switched the station back to electric -- but the train is still stuck in a netherland between the depot and the station. It won't go to the station, and it won't go back into the depot either. Here's a screen shot to give you an idea of how it looks.

[image]

I have no idea how to delete it. It loses me a decent sum each year. What can I do?

Comment: try removing that depot and putting down some tracks, see if that train is willing to go on the tracks?  Also, check to see if it really is a electric station you put down, not just a regular station piece.

Comment: It won't let me remove the depot, says a train is in the way. It's an electric station but when I try to convert to make sure it says "no suitable track".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build another depot somewhere and connect it with that track, build the cheapest train you can find, manage to crash it with the other train. In a while both trains will disappear.

**Cons** are that you'll instantly lose reputation in your station, but as time passes, you'll get it back to normal.

Comment: the problem is it looks like he can't put a depot on the other side, at least not easily due to that station on the hill.

Comment: changed, @yx., this solution is almost the same...

Comment: good solution though :)